# ServiceStack MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider in MVC Controller produces no roles

Tags: servicestack

We have the following authentication setup for our ServiceStack MVC implementation

```
    public void Configure(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        var AppSettings = appHost.AppSettings;

        var providers = new IAuthProvider[] {
                new ServiceStack.Auth.NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings),
                new MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider(AppSettings),
                ConfigureJwtAuthProviderReader(appHost),
            };          

        var authFeature = new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), providers)
        {   
            IncludeAssignRoleServices = false,
            IncludeRegistrationService = false
        };

        appHost.Plugins.Add(authFeature);
    }

    private JwtAuthProviderReader ConfigureJwtAuthProviderReader(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        var settings = new AzureAdOptions();
        appHost.GetConfiguration().Bind("AzureAd", settings);
        var jwt = settings.GetJWTProviderReader(appHost.Config.DebugMode);

        jwt.PopulateSessionFilter = (session, payload, request) =>
        {
            var upn = payload.GetValueOrDefault("upn") ?? string.Empty;
            var uniqueName = payload.GetValueOrDefault("unique_name");
            var appid = payload.GetValueOrDefault("appid");
            session.Email ??= (upn.Contains("@", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? upn : null);
            session.UserName ??= uniqueName ?? appid ?? string.Empty;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(session.DisplayName))
            {
                session.DisplayName = session.UserName;
            }

            session.DisplayName = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(session.DisplayName);
        };
        return jwt;
    }
```

In our mvc controller

```
    this.AuthUser.Roles
```

is an empty collection for all users authenticating via MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider. It is however populated for users using ConfigureJwtAuthProviderReader.

**EDIT: See comment from @DeonHeyns for solution**

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a custom `MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider` and override `OnAuthenticatedAsync()` and update your answer with the JSON info contained in MS Auth Token? i.e.

```
public class MyMicrosoftAuthProvider : MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider
{
    public MyMicrosoftAuthProvider(IAppSettings appSettings) : base(appSettings) {}

    public override Task<IHttpResult> OnAuthenticatedAsync(
        IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, 
        IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo,
        CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        var json = authInfo.ToJson(); //What's in this?
        json.Print();
        return base.OnAuthenticatedAsync(authService, session, tokens, authInfo, token);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for the response, I inspected the token under tokens and it seems like the roles are not on the token at all. I'm not sure why yet.

Comment: If i change the scopes to include the identity token then the identity token has the relevant roles (not sure why the access token don't have them). What would you recommend to add the roles from the identity token toke the roles. Is there public functionality to decode jwt tokens? And can I just populate the roles on IAuthSession after decoding?

Comment: @Murdock Yeah you can populate `session.Roles` to include the roles with the authenticated user session. For public functionality do you mean https://jwt.io? BTW what scopes did you use to return the relevant roles?

Comment: @Murdock I ran into the same issue. Firstly you need to assign the App Roles via Azure AD. Secondly the MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider will populate the roles now (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/1241)